# His had been a life with only one tragedy

Tags: grammar, word-order

Why author changes conventional word order, I think like that - 'His life had been with only one tragedy'?

> **His had been a life with only one tragedy**—the simultaneous death of his young wife and the stillborn child who would have been a sister
>   to the one-year-old Charles.

THE FRENCH LIEUTENANT’S WOMAN
by John Fowles

Comment: 'His' here is like 'mine', not 'my'. *His (life) had been a life with only one tragedy*...

Comment: @dan, I think your comment can be transformed into a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

'His' here is like 'mine', not 'my'. *His (life) had been a life with only one tragedy*...

Compare to:

> ‘Is that your car?’ ‘No, **mine** is parked over the road.’

Comment: It sounds strange because (or since) it is the beginning of the paragraph, but isn't the continuation.